# QByteArray value compare

Tags: c++, qt, hex, comparison, qbytearray

Why the statement:

```
QByteArray data (initialized somehow);
if(data.at(0) == 0xFF)
do_something();
```

gives such warning:
comparison is always false due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits].

You can initialize `QByteArray` with `0xff` value:

```
QByteArray data;
data[0]=0xff;
```

This gives no warning or error, so why cant you compare it with the `0xff` value?

Answer (score 3):

`QByteArray` is Qt safe way to handle `const char *`. The range for char is from -128 to 127. So you can assign or compare your value:

```
if(data.at(0) == 0xFF)
{
}
```

But compiler generates warning that condition always `false`. Char value will never be 255 due to range. It is not `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following expression:

```
if((unsigned char)(data.at(0)==0xFF){}
```